# C# Chart: How to display relative time on x axis

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, .net-4.0

I have `DataTable` with some data (measurements) that I want to display on chart. Each record contains `DataTime` value - real date-time when measurements were taken and `TimeSpan` value - relative time of measurement (time passed from the moment when 1st measurement was taken).

I want to be able to switch between two types of x-axis values: absolute and relative.
It's easy to switch between those values with simple

```
chart.DataSource = table;        // table with columns: Time, Relative, D1, D2...
series.XValueMember = "Time";    // absolute - DateTime
series.XValueMember = "Relative";// relative - at 1st TimeSpan, now double
```

The problem is that DataPoints do not accept `TimeSpan` as X values. I tried using `double` (`TimeSpan.TotalDays`) with label formating

```
chart.ChartAreas[ 0 ].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd HH:mm:ss";
```

but the value displayed for values of double below 1 (before reaching 24 hours/1 day) is 30 xx:xx:xx ...

Where that 30 come from? or rather how can i correctly display relative time with WinForms Chart control?

---

edit:
ok, i know where that 30 came from, it's the OADate:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate( 0.0 );
```

assigns the value of `dt = 1899-12-30 00:00:00`, so in chart the double value is converted that way to DateTime (quite obvious converion now that i think about it) and then converted to string with format specified.

---

I have also checked with ILSpy, that this is exactly what happens under the hood: (fragment of System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.ValueConverter.FormatValue(...) method)

```
if (valueType == ChartValueType.DateTime || valueType == ChartValueType.DateTimeOffset || valueType == ChartValueType.Date)
    {
        ...
        text2 = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, text, new object[]
        {
            DateTime.FromOADate(value)
        });
    }
    else
    {
        if (valueType == ChartValueType.Time)
        {
            ...
            text2 = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, text, new object[]
            {
                DateTime.FromOADate(value)
            });
        }
```

---

Either way, that brings me to my basic question - how to display what i want to display.
Using DateTime this way or another will always give me positive number of days (something between 1 and 31).

The result can be "days HH:mm:ss" or "total hours:mm:ss", where total hours can grow over 24 and don't get reset to 0 when a full day passes.

Comment: Can you try : `series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;`

Comment: i tried switching between ChartValueType.DateTime and Time already. this does not change anything.

Comment: So what is the content of XValueMember = "Relative"? Really the realtive times? In what range are they? Within 24h?

Comment: double, 
at first those were TimeSpans, but after I tried using it with chart I got the "we don't work with TimeSpans" exception, so I've switched to double. this value equals to value of TimeSpan.TotalDays, so it starts with 0.xxxx, when a whole day passes, you get 1.xxxx etc. fractional part equals to hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds when you treat them as a fractional part of a day